# Code issue with parsing xml in Android, trying to use InputStream

Tags: android, xml, parsing, inputstream

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I've only recently started learn coding with the end goal of making myself a simple maintenance checklist app for myself.

I'm trying to include a list of part numbers I can call from the main screen app. I have converted the original list from an excel file to an xml file using Microsoft Access, because I keep reading it's a preferred file format in Android. I’m trying to use most of the code found on this site ( http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/ ), but I’m trying to utilize the xml file that I’ve already added to R.raw instead of pulling it in from an http.

I’m assuming I have to replace the getxml order with an InputStream command, but I'm not sure how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use getResources().getXML(resourceid)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm having trouble to getting this too work for me.  I get this error if I use the code as follows;

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: where are you calling that method? Is not an Activity? When you use that method from activity then just call, others you need an context instance like activity etc..

Comment: In the example I'm using it calls ( String xml = XmlDecode.getXML(); Document doc = XmlDecode.XMLfromString(xml); )
Then in my XmlDecode class I have ( Public static String getXML(); getResources().getXML(resourceid)

Comment: getResources() is not static method. It can't be called from static  method. call it from the instance of context. context instance can be passed from activity.

Comment: Oh I think I'm getting this. I just have to replace the calling command, remove the created function, and just utilize getResources within the activity I want to use it in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . 
Step 1 : get xml which list of item to be displayed (Done)
Step 2 : Parse xml via use of XML parser like SAX and convert it into Map/List
Step 3 : Add this Map/List to Simple Adapter of your list View .

I can also share code if u want .

Comment: Should I just not use the code structure provided in the link and utilize the SAX method then? or am I supposed to use the  the SAX parser inside current structure?